# Javascript JSON data with DataTables

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

I am using a JavaScript with jQuery DataTables but I have been having problem in loading the JSON data into the Bootstrap table.

This is a sample of the table

```
[ { name: 'Bryant Stone',       hobbies: 'Football',       favorite_team: 'Sea hawks',       height: '5 Feet 10 in' },
  { name: 'Jesse Smith',        hobbies: 'boxing',          favorite_team: 'Spurs',           height: '6 feet 6 in' },
  { name: 'Emily Wyclef',       hobbies: 'cooking',         favorite_team: 'Venus Williams',  height: '5 feet 2 in' }
]
```

In JavaScript I get the data in this format and put it inside JavaScript like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(\'#respondent\').dataTable({
        destroy: true,
        data: jsonStr1,
        columns:[   
                {title:"Name", data: "name"},
                {title:"Hobbies", data: "hobbies"},
                {title:"Favorite team" ,data: "favorite_team"},
                {title: "Height" ,data: "height"}
            ]
    });
})
```

When I load the page it shows my data in the console but a DataTables dialog box shows this message

```
DataTable warning table id=respondent-
Requested unknown parameter 'name' for
row0, column 0. For information more.....
```

I don't know what else I can do. It has taken the whole day from me. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to all who helped by providing some answers all of which i have done.
This is my html

```
<table class="display" id="respondent">
    <thead>

        <tr>

            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Hobbies</th>
            <th>Favorite Team</th>
            <th>Height</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
</table>
```

I have made needed typo correction to the code displayed earlier
but I still keep on getting this error message

```
DataTables warning: table id=respondent- 
Requested unknown parameter 'name' for 
row 0, column 0, for more information about this 
error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

I went to the link but could not get anything helpful.
After the above message, the table get filled up with empty spaces
and after going to some pages I see just one character in the first 
cell only. Those characters either letter or braces I do not know where
they came from because I could not see such sequence in my json data even 
numbers shows up.
It keeps on baffling me I do not know what else to do.
Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I discovered that the problem was that the data was in a string.
Does anyone know how to convert string in javascript to object without using eval(). JSON.parse return string and not object which is what is being looked for.

Comment: Did you mean to escape that one part? `$(\'#respondent\')`

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with that code (in order to make it work) -> **http://jsfiddle.net/wkf2z48t/**

Answer (score 1):

Minor changes:

1. `,` missing after `data` option
2. Column is passed as **favourite_team** (British english) but data has **favorite_team** (American English)
3. Column contains **hobbies** where as data contains **hobbies** in the first row while **hobbie** in the other rows. You gotta match them.
4. Use `title` option in the columns to show the header name

Info: That error/alert is usually due to missing columns in the data.

Here's a code snippet fixing the above:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
var jsonStr1 = [ { name: 'Bryant Stone',       hobbies: 'Football',       favorite_team: 'Sea hawks',       height: '5 Feet 10 in' },
  { name: 'Jesse Smith',        hobbies: 'boxing',          favorite_team: 'Spurs',           height: '6 feet 6 in' },
  { name: 'Emily Wyclef',       hobbies: 'cooking',         favorite_team: 'Venus Williams',  height: '5 feet 2 in' }
];

    $('#respondent').dataTable({
        destroy: true,
        data: jsonStr1,
        columns:[   
                {title: "name", data: "name"},
                {title: "hobbies", data: "hobbies"},
                {title: "favorite_team", data: "favorite_team"},
                {title: "height", data: "height"}
            ]
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css"/>


<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="respondent" class="display">
  <thead>
    
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, i have made needed changes, and added title options but it the same thing with the error message

Comment: Can you match your code with the one I’ve posted? If it still doesn’t work, could you please post your new code with the changes?

Comment: thanks code has been updated. Modification has been shown. Appreciate your help. I hope that I can get this completed

Comment: Seems like it is working fine. Here's a jsfiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/ohj926xm/

Comment: It was a problem of converting a string to object.

Answer (score 1):

Typo errors of column names - hobbies are mentioned as "hobbie"  and favo**u**rite_team as favorite_team.

Maintain same property names for all objects to avoid that error

Code sample for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vzNXPe

HTML:

```
<table class="display" id="respondent">
    <thead>

        <tr>

            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Hobbies</th>
            <th>Favorite Team</th>
            <th>Height</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
</table>
```

JS

```
var jsonStr1 = [ { name: 'Bryant Stone',  hobbies: 'Football', favorite_team: 'Sea hawks',       height: '5 Feet 10 in' },
  { name: 'Jesse Smith', hobbies: 'boxing', favorite_team: 'Spurs',           height: '6 feet 6 in' },
  { name: 'Emily Wyclef', hobbies: 'cooking',  favorite_team: 'Venus Williams',  height: '5 feet 2 in' }
]

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#respondent').dataTable({
        destroy: true,
        data: jsonStr1,
        columns:[   
            {title:"Name", data: "name"},
            {title:"Hobbies", data: "hobbies"},
            {title:"Favorite team" ,data: "favorite_team"},
            {title: "Height" ,data: "height"}
        ]
    });
} );
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I have made the changes but thng still remains the same

Comment: Can you try to replace your code with my code and try ??

Comment: updated codepen and answer, not seeing any error from my side , are you using any css from your side?- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vzNXPe